# Making an API call over SSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ssl

I have a method that works just fine for calls to non-ssl apis, but it gives me the following error response whenever I request https-only apis:

```
757: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

The method is fairly straightforward:

```
def my_service_api_call(path = nil, query = nil)
  my_service_api_key = ENV["MY_SERVICE_KEY"]
  api_path = "#{path}/?api_key=#{my_service_api_key}&#{query}"
  url = URI.parse(api_path)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(api_path)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http| http.request(req) }
  JSON.parse(res.body)["results"]
end
```

This works great over http but fails over https-only.  Is there an equivalent way to do HTTPS requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a more elegant way to reuse your instance of `Net::HTTP` *and* enable requests over HTTPS:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # Sets the HTTPS verify mode
@data = http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

Notice the use of `use_ssl`. From [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-use_ssl-3D):

> Turn on/off SSL. This flag must be set before starting session. If you change use_ssl value after session started, a Net::HTTP object raises IOError.

Note also that the usage of `VERIFY_NONE` is controversial, since [it doesn't force the validity of of certificates to be checked](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-cure-nethttps-risky-default-https-behavior-4010.html). For many applications and users, this will not bear any negative ramifications. In cases where certificate validity *should* be checked, [this post](http://docs.seattlerb.org/net-http-persistent/Net/HTTP/Persistent.html) suggests the following:

> Securely transfer the correct certificate and update the default certificate store or set the ca file instead.

Comment: Gives `undefined method 'use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>`

Comment: Ahh, yes. I hadn't notice your invocation of the `GET` method. That said, I've updated my answer to reflect a more holistic approach to HTTPS requests.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Since it did, would you kindly consider [accepting this answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: @tyler check my version of the answer you might need to specify ssl_version to prevent differing behaviors

Comment: @zeantsoi yes, but I have to wait a few minutes before SO will let me mark it

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [use_ssl](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-use_ssl-3D) to true:

like this:

```
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        http.ssl_version = :SSLv3
```